# Setting up remote email server LInux WHM/Cpanel

Tags: email, cpanel, remote-server, whm

I have 2 new WHM/Cpanel boxes on linux.

Box 1 on ip x.x.x.1

Box 2 on ip x.x.x.10

Did a Cpanel move of multiple account onto box 1. They all share the same IP as box 1, x.x.x.1.

I want to port all outgoing emails from box 1 to be sent through and by box 2, where box 2 would be a dedicated mail server.

Box 2 is clean, no Cpanel accounts created on it.

I do not want to update DNS at registrar until I have this setup.

Between all the sites, about 1 million emails per day go out which is why I want a dedicated mail server, box 2.

I am not a complete novice, but everything I am finding online to help me configure this is not working. I thought it would be as easy as changing the DNS zones of the accounts on box 1, changing the mail record to go to the ip of box 2. However when test sending email from box 1 the source shows it came from box 1.

I have also added the ip of box 2 into the Configure Remote Service IPs as a remote mail server and have set the accounts to use Remote Host instead of Localhost.

I thought this would be as easy as setting up remote mysql, which I can do. It appears there is much more that needs to be done that I am not finding info on.

I do not have the time, money, nor the experience to setup qmail which would be ideal. All I want right now is for all outgoing email from box 1 to be handled by box 2.

Do I need to update DNS records to point to the new server first before this can work? Do I need to create an account on box 2 to make this work? Do I need to Cluster in box 2 for remote email service?

Is this not easy? lol!

Maybe setting up box 2 as remote mysql server and having that as a dedicated mysql server would be just as effective, if not easier, to setup? One way or another email and mysql need to be separated.

Answer (score 0):

> One way or another email and mysql need to be separated.

It is much easier to set up a remote MySQL server (this can be set up in WHM) than it is to have a mail server on a different machine than the cPanel server where the accounts are hosted.

Apparently you can add entries to `/etc/ips.remotemail` to specify servers that will handle mail for a domain. I've never tried this, but I expect there will be some difficulty with configuring this on the remote mail server...

Honestly, I'm not sure there is a very robust and well-documented/supported way of doing this.

You should request this on features.cpanel.net and see what happens.